# Problem with moving static folders

Tags: python, django, dotcloud

I have a problem with uploading a django app to dotcloud. I'm using the code below to change django's admin panel static files to /static/admin_media, but it gives me the following error when deploying:

```
2011-08-14 13:22:35 [www.0] Traceback (most recent call last):
2011-08-14 13:22:35 [www.0]   File "./postinstall", line 23, in <module>
2011-08-14 13:22:35 [www.0]     os.symlink(mediadir, staticlink)
2011-08-14 13:22:35 [www.0] OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and the code:

```
import os
# To import anything under django.*, we must set this variable.
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'kalvin.settings'
# Import the admin module. The media directory is right under it!
import django.contrib.admin
# Retrieve the absolute path of the admin module.
admindir = os.path.dirname(django.contrib.admin.__file__)
# Add /media behind it.
mediadir = os.path.join(admindir, 'media')
# Compute the path of the symlink under the static directory.
staticlink = os.path.join('static', 'admin_media')
# If the link already exists, delete it.
if os.path.islink(staticlink):
    os.unlink(staticlink)
# Install the correct link.
os.symlink(mediadir, staticlink)
```

Comment: Please fix your question title. A list of technologies (which we already have in the tags, btw) does not describe the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-do-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository).

I needed an empty folder named `static`, but git didn't transfer it to the server because it was empty.

Creating `.gitignore` inside the folder fixed the problem.